# fromArray, merge in Doctrine2

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I have a simple table with some fields: id, name.... It will appear in a grid in the browser and the user can add/edit records. That's why in save action I will give array with records where the new records id is a negative number for example:

```
array[0] = {"id" => "-1", "name" => "New record 1"}
array[1] = {"id" => "-2", "name" => "New record 2"}
array[2] = {"id" => "1", "name" => "Exist record 1"}
array[3] = {"id" => "2", "name" => "Exist record 2"}
```

In doctrine 1 I used this:

```
if (array[x]["id"] < 0) {
  $record = new $MyRecord();
  $record->fromArray(array[x]);
} else {
  $record = Doctrine::getTable($MyRecord)->find(array[x]["id"]);
  $record->merge(array[x]);
}
```

but how can I do this in D2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my code where I create/update I usually pass in the array, then loop over it assigning each member variable of the class. Or if there is something more specific I need to do, I just manually assign each value from the array to the class member variables. Doctrine 2 requires you to be much more explicit in the way you do some things. Here is an example method from a service class.

```
public function createPage(array $data)
{
    $page = new \Entity\Page();

    $page->setName($data['name']);
    $page->setUrl($data['url']);
    $page->setContent($data['content']);
    $page->setSite($this->em->getReference('Entity\Site', $data['site']));

    $this->em->persist($page);
}
```

Here's another example with the loop:

```
public function createUser(array $data)
{
    $user = new \Entity\User();
    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
        $user->'set' . ucfirst($key)($value);
    }

    $this->em->persist($user);
}
```

The second example with the loop will only work if you know your entity doesn't have any references to other entities (like in the first example where page has a site).

Comment: I modified @JeremyHicks function and created a new function in my entity class because PHP gave syntax errors. Here is my revised code:    /**
     * Set all submitted form values at the same time.
     * @param field_type $allFormElements
     */
    public function setAllFormElements ($allFormElements)
    {
        foreach ($allFormElements as $name => $value) {
            $this->$name = $value;
        }
    }

Comment: @Jeremy Hicks I'm sorry but where is merge command? You are showing only "insert" command.